# How to create a simple custom animation inside unreal engine5?

Tags: animation, game-development, unreal-engine5, unreal

I have been at this for more than 12 hours now and I can't seem to find a way to create a simple animation inside unreal. Everywhere i look i get told to make an animation elsewhere and import it but I refuse to believe I cant create the animation inside the engine. I want to specify that I am not talking about level sequencer since I want to make an animation for a component inside an actor which i will place in multiple levels in multiple spots. I simply want to have a static or skeletal mesh move in 1 direction for a few frames and then teleport back and loop again. This can be done in Unity in less than a minute but for some reason in unreal it seems to be very complicated. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I tried everything i could find online.

Answer (score 0):

12 hours is a long time to be on the same problem, I feel for you buddy!

You're not gonna like this but Sequencer can do more than you think.  You can bake out the animation from Sequencer, creating an animation asset.  It will be just like any other animation you get from Epic, marketplace, mixamo, etc.  Then, you can place that animation on your actor or multiple actors on multiple levels, and each actor will play that animation. Just like placing around a bunch of BP_Characters around the level will play their idle animation.  For an example, watch the [UE5 guided tour by Chris Murphy](https://dev.epicgames.com/community/learning/talks-and-demos/vyn9/unreal-engine-5-guided-tour) found on UE's home page. Towards the end of the video, he quickly animates a sea monster and places a few around the level.  That sounds similar to what you want to do.

Alternatively, Materials can be used for simple animations like a fish swimming, trees blowing in the wind, etc.  Optionally, there's a different system for cloth-like effects, backpack straps, and some types of hair using Chaos.  Not that you can't use Animation assets, but Chaos would give better results

It is common to animate in Blender or other DCC and import into UE, but I think it's unnecessary for simple animation or modifications to complex animations.

Check out [UE learning](https://dev.epicgames.com/community/search?query=animation%20&applications=unreal_engine&types=tutorial,course,learning_path) for more info on animations.  "Animation Ecosystem for Game Development" is a good start for games, but there's also content for linear stuff like movies if that's your jam.

I hope that answers your question!